# Fragment not attached to Activity, best solution?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an Activity with google map, and a fragment, with address (start/stop) fields in it.

When `LocationManager` return user's location first time, I'm try to update start field in addresses fragment.

But sometimes I get the exception:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment CoordinatesFragment not attached to Activity`

And I don't understand why.
I know that there are method `Fragment.isAdded()`, wich I can use, but it seems not a best way to solve the problem.

Also sometimes I get this exception when try to restore state (in `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state)` i get data and in `onMapLoaded()` try to use)

Comment: How do you add your fragment?

Answer (score 2):

Check this;
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isAdded()

```
if(!isAdded()) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: I know about this method, but it isn't enought. Becouse I need to wait when fragment will be added, if it is not.

Answer (score 2):

If you could use RxJava 2, you could have the result of LocationManager in an Observable cached, and the Fragment could subscribe for the result.

If the result have arrived and the Fragment is not yet attached, the Fragment will recieve the result when it is attached. Else it will receive it instantly.

I recommend for you to learn how RxJava can be used to tackle such problems.

Comment: Even though RxJava can be used in such case to observe stream of location, we should not be proposing learning/adding Rx just to solve this problem. Just storing and checking last location observed from LocationManager should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void setFragment(Fragment fragmentToSet, String tag) {

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        if (fragment != null && !fragment.isAdded()) {
            transaction.replace(R.id.home_container, fragment, tag);
        } else if (fragmentToSet != null && !fragmentToSet.isAdded()) {
            transaction.replace(R.id.home_container, fragmentToSet, tag);
        }
    }else{
        transaction.replace(R.id.home_container, fragment, tag);
    }
    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    manager.executePendingTransactions();
}
```

Try using this function to set the fragment in your activity. Its working good for me. You can save the savedInstanceState from your activity's onCreate

Comment: Watch out when using the `commitAllowingStateLoss` method, because the documentation says `This is dangerous because the commit can be lost if the activity needs to later be restored from its state...` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction

Answer (score 1):

While utilizing `isAdded()` is the simplest solution, I encountered a situation where using this method was not the best choice. So I adopted another approach:

First, I created a global variable of type `FragmentActivity`.

Then, inside the `onViewCreated()` method, I initialized its value like this:

`fragmentActivity = requiredActivity();`

After that, in the `onAttach()` method, I casted the context in parameter to FragmentActivity and assigned it to that global variable in the following way:

```java
    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.fragmentActivity = (FragmentActivity) context;
    }
```

In this manner, instead of using `requireActivity()` or `requireContext()` I could use `fragmentActivity` and avoid IllegalStateException.